What is the 3x3 magic square trick for only 3 numbers?
The magic square we are talking about is not one with sequential numbers. It is 3x3 and we are given 3 numbers but not the magic number.










A
-59
522


D
E
F


G
H
266



These are the simple rules to solving magic squares I have gleaned and I am looking to solve this using them or an extra similar simple rule I have missed.

If you have a whole line, column or diagonal you add them up to get the magic number.
If you have the magic number and 2 numbers in a line, you subtract those 2 from the magic number to get the last number in that line.
The magic number is always 3x the middle.
2 opposites always equal the other set: diagonal corners = other diagonal corners, horizontal edges = vertical edges. E.g. A + I = C + G. B + H = D + F
The middle is always half of the 2 numbers that go through it making a line. E.g. the diagonal line from top left to bottom right or the horizontal line D E F etc.
A corner is always half of the sum of the 2 sides that form a "T" with it. E.g. I = (B + D)/2 or A = (F + H)/2

None of these seem to help me solve the puzzle above though.
There are a limited unique layouts of 3x3 squares with 3 numbers (16?), so what is the missing strategy/trick to do this layout?
I'm not looking for the mathematical proof of it, I'm just looking for each of the steps to solve this using rules described like above and another simple rule that I might have missed.

Is the magic number along the diagonals?

Without the diagonals, you have 6 equations and 7 unknowns - many solutions. With the diagonal you have 8 unknown that could result no solution.

There are many ways to solve this magic square, but here is a way only using the rules that you gave.  Start with this one:

 A corner is always half of the sum of the 2 sides that form a "T" with it. E.g. I = (B + D)/2

Just plug in the numbers for that exact example:

 266 = (-59 + D) / 2
 D = 266*2 + 59 = 591

From there apply the rule to another corner:

 C = (D + H) / 2
 522 = (591 + H) / 2
 H = 522*2 - 591 = 453

Then apply another rule of yours:

 The middle is always half of the 2 numbers that go through it making a line.

 E = (B + H) / 2
 E = (-59 + 453) / 2
 E = 197

From here, use the rule:

 The magic number is always 3x the middle.

 M = 3 * E
 M = 3 * 197 = 591

Once you have the magic number, you can easily fill in the rest:

  128  -59  522
 591  197 -197
-128  453  266


I somehow missed that first step because I have been practicing getting the corner from the 2 sides and it made me blind to seeing that it equally applies here!

It is fairly well known that the magic constant of a 3x3 square is

 3E

Proof:
Let X be the magic constant. Then

 3E = (A+E+I)+(B+E+H)+(C+E+G)-(A+B+C)-(G+H+I)
 3E = X+X+X-X-X = X

Now to the given problem:

 A+E+266=A-59+522
 The A’s cancel giving:
 E = 197
 And the constant X=591

The rest of the cells are then easy to fill in.

Down voted because of not following the request to use simple to follow rules instead of difficult to follow equations.

This answer can be improved to explicitly mention the simple rule used. In this case, a diagonal sum (A+E+I) equals a row sum (A+B+C). Or, to align more with the examples of the simple rules, then: "Take one cell. The sum of the other two cells in the row or in the column or in the diagonal have the same sum. E,g., take A, we have B+C = E+H, or take E, we have B+H=D+F" (the second example overlaps with the diagonal rule)

What's not simple to follow here? I'm genuinely confused

At first this answer was also slightly confusing to me because I couldn't see how to "proof" part would lead to the part after it. Like it felt that they should somehow be related, not realizing that it's not a continuation at all. Maybe just leaving the proof part out would have made it more clear.

See the accepted answer for adding a new simple rule (after my edit is approved)

@TimSeifert I'm just following OP's examples in the question ‍♂️

@justhalf Sure thing, this was directed more at OP. Tbh I still don't see how the rule about "toroidal" lines from the accepted answer (which is a perfectly fine, don't get me wrong) is any more "simple" than Jaap's direct application of the definition

@TimSeifert Actually I solved the magic square first using "A+E+266=A+59+522" (i.e. the same way as this answer) since that was the simplest way to do it.  But then I wondered why the OP couldn't solve it using any of their many rules, so I figured out a how to apply their rules to solve it.
